# Selecting a class inside of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues with selecting a class inside of a class. It seems that the element(s) do not want to show. I have tried multiple methods including .find() and a simple (".outer .inner") selection but neither seem to work for me.

Below is the code in a simple format to hopefully clarify the question.

https://jsfiddle.net/ruo92tuc/

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="section01">Section 1</a>

<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>

<a href="#" class="sub2">Sub menu 2</a>
<a href="#" class="sub2">Sub menu 2</a>
<a href="#" class="sub2">Sub menu 2</a>
<a href="#" class="sub2">Sub menu 2</a>

<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>
<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>
<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>
<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".sub1").hide();
$(".sub2").hide();

$(".section01").click(function() {
   $('.section01').find(".sub1").show();
});
```

Comment: The elements are not nested so `find` will never find them as a descendant element. Reorganize your HTML. Nested `ULs` with `LIs` are a good way of doing menus/submenus :)

Comment: Or use `$('.section01 ~ .sub1')` to get all `.sub1` siblings after `.section01` if nesting is not appropriate.

Comment: @Quantastical: It's a menu with submenus. I'd be surprised if nesting wasn't a good idea. Otherwise you need another way to determine the menu hierarchy :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I just wanted to provide an alternative in case A: the user can't change HTML or B: a future user has a similar problem that doesn't warrant nesting.

Comment: @Quantastical: The chances of this example being unchangeable HTML, or not warranting nesting, is close to zero, but I take your point :)

Comment: As an alternative, you can do nested menus with `ULs`, `LIs` and `CSS` alone (no code). e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/kruxor/cRqhP/2/light/

Answer (score 0):

Per your question, what you need is to use `siblings`, not `find`. What `find` does is searches ***ALL*** children of that element. `children` searches ***immediate*** child elements of the selector. So, if we keep your same HTML,

```
<a href="#" class="section01">Section 1</a>

<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>

<a href="#" class="sub2">Sub menu 2</a>
<a href="#" class="sub2">Sub menu 2</a>
<a href="#" class="sub2">Sub menu 2</a>
<a href="#" class="sub2">Sub menu 2</a>

<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>
<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>
<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>
<a href="#" class="sub1">Sub menu 1</a>

$('.section01').click(function(e) {
   $(this).siblings('.sub1').show();
});
```

Comment: The first line of the question "selecting class within a class" indicates there is a much deeper problem here :)

Comment: True, but keeping the same HTML structure as his represents the issue. Perhaps his wording was incorrect?

Comment: In my experience `menu + submenu = nesting`, but anything could be the case here :)

Answer (score -1):

i updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ruo92tuc/3/

```
$(".section01").click(function() {
  $(document).find(".sub1").show();
});
```

and if you want to use your javascript function the way you wrote it, you need to nest the html elements inside of each other.

```
<div class="1">
  <div class="1.1"></div>
  <div class="1.1"></div>
</div>
<div class="2">
  <div class="2.1"></div>
  <div class="2.1"></div>
</div>
```

and js:

```
$(".1").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".1.1").show();
});
```

what happens is, that your jQuery class selector selects all of the html elements with the given class. if you select `$(document).find(".test")` all html elements with class `test` inside of the document will be returned. If you do `$('.test').find(".test2")` all html elements with class `test2` inside of the HTML elements with class `test` will be returned.

further information: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

greetings and happy new year ;)

Comment: Functions, but defeats the intended purpose (menus with submenus). The HTML/DOM needs to be restructured to do this correctly.

Comment: my final answer takes care of this

Comment: Your answer is correct, and meets the requirements of the question. However, an clarification is required. Or he will think to reuse this for these subsection 2. But this solution will open all subsection 2 if he clicks on sub1. fe. I should advise him to restructure the DOM for easy management and for being future proof.

Comment: somebody rejected in a bad time - now the fiddle is updated correctly

Comment: Is it final now? (not my DV BTW) :)

Comment: just like you said - code is never final xD but the menus can now be opened and closed, and both of the ways i explained above can be seen in the code

Comment: Ever hear of `.toggle()`? You can throw away about 60% of your code :>

Comment: yes but i thought that the princip of solving such problems can be seen better in that way - i also would not use any class selectors for menu links - its always better to use IDs in such a case. But i did not want to change the native code too much

Comment: I would not do it this way (without nesting) but here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ruo92tuc/5/ Same functionality with half the calories. Feel free to use :)

Comment: yea much more beautiful - in my example there is a nested and a "non-nested" way

Comment: It's *your* example I changed... still has both ways :)